# Risk of injecting an HttpServletRequest class into a Service class

Tags: java, servlets

I am injecting the HttpServletRequest class into a class with the @Service annotation passing the instance of the HttpServletRequest class to a utility class (AuthorizationUtils) to get the authorization header. Is there any risk in this, such as my AuthorizationUtils trying to call the method below and my service class or HttpServletRequest class already being destroyed?

`request.getHeader("Authorization")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would avoid doing that (for architectural reasons), but no, there is no risk.

What would be incorrect would be to pass the request to a separate thread (or an async method, which is executed in a separate thread). Not because the class would be "destroyed" (that doesn't exist), but because the specification says:

> Each request object is valid only within the scope of a servlet’s service method. [...] Containers commonly recycle request objects in order to avoid the performance overhead of request object creation. The developer must be aware that maintaining references to request objects for which startAsync has not been called outside the scope described above is not recommended as it may have indeterminate results.

If your service is synchronous, then the `service()` method of the servlet hasn't returned yet when your service method is executed, so that's fine.